# Debugging GTK+ on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, gtk, visual-studio-debugging

I downloaded GTK+ for windows and included the library in my Visual Studio 2010 and it works fine, but I don't know how to output text to the console or any other form for debugging.
I tried `g_print("hi");` and even `std::cout << "cout test";` but nothing shows up.

Is there a way to debug in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gcc there is the [`-mwindows`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Windows-Options.html) flag that sets the PE header subsystem type to get a GUI application. Without it you'll get two windows: one with the GTK+ GUI and one with a console where stdout and stderr are redirected. I suspect there is something similar also in Visual Studio, maybe specifying in some way your application is console based.